# JSON : how to put JSON element item different place

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Is there any simple way to put `count` put side of href like

result expecting like this 
`<li><a id="{ID}" class="item" href="#">London</a>(25)</li>`

**DEMO**  http://jsfiddle.net/aKEDJ/15/

any advice much appreciated

Comment: What is your question.

Comment: @PSL just edited the question, please let me know if you need more details. Sorry for my bad English

Comment: Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
   var listr = "<li> <a href='#' class=\"item\" id=\"{ID}\">{DATA}</a>({COUNT})</li>";

   //Code follows
    strhtml = strhtml.replace(/{COUNT}/, jsonStr[i].count)
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5WK8d/)

This renders as:

```
<li> <a href="#" class="item" id="4">Moscow</a>(12)</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would do a even bigger rewrite of your function than what I'm putting below to make formatting your HTML a little easier.

Every variable used in the function below has been `var`d and I moved as much of the logic outside of the loop as I could. This should (hopefully) make it easier to follow.

```
function insertData(NinCol, Colcount) {
    var ul_format = "<ul id=\"{ID}\">{DATA} </ul>", // format of <ul>
        li_format = "<li> <a href='#' class=\"item\" id=\"{ID}\">{NAME}</a>({COUNT})</li>", // format of <li>
        re = /({ID})|({NAME})|({COUNT})/g, // single regex for formatting
        re_function = function (id, name, count) { // generate replace function
            return function (m, mid, mname, mcount) { // replace found item
                return (mid && id) || (mname && name) || (mcount && count) || '';
            };
        },
        html_str = "", i;
    for (i = lastIndex; i < lastIndex + NinCol; ++i) {
        html_str += li_format.replace( // apply all formatting
            re,
            re_function(i, jsonStr[i].name, jsonStr[i].count)
        );
    }
    html_str = ul_format
        .replace(/{ID}/, Colcount)       // give <ul> it's id
        .replace(/{DATA}/, html_str);    // and add all <li>s
    $('#destinations').append(html_str); // then append
    lastIndex += NinCol;
}
```

Updated fiddle for this [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/4CUf4/).
Another alternate way to write `re` would be `/{(?:(ID)|(NAME)|(COUNT))}/g`

You also need to consider that your code as it is may very well produce a non-unique *id*, which would invalidate your HTML.